# Working with AutoLayout using UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I am working with autoLayout, I want to place a UIlabel on UITableViewCell, which should be always at the right of the cell and the center of right.

So here is what I want to achieve

[image]

So here you can **see label named RC** which I am talking about.

So here my cell height changes dynamically, so whatever be the text height I always want to be the center right.

2) Now as the cell height depends **on the text of the label sentence**. I want to make sure that if the cell has the default height and it will not decrease below it. It can increase to any height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your label go to `editor` then select `vertical center in container`, also fix it using the `trailing space` from super view and set fit size to content and it should work. For dynamic tableViewCell height created using autolayout find the [TUTORIAL](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout). This will help you a lot.

Comment: hey this works, but label height gets cut if I invert the label using label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; Otherwise it is fine. any thought on that. Also can you help me with my second issue above

Comment: @Ranjit No idea but this should not happen if you are using it like [RC.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
        RC.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2); after this, use [self.view layoutIfNeeded] or [cell layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: @Ranjit use [self.view layoutIfNeeded] or [cell layoutIfNeeded] after rotating the RC label

Comment: yes, I am going to accept it. Can you please have a look at my second doubt in above question

Comment: Ok bro just go through the TUTORIAL link I have mentioned in answer. May be it will help you regarding maintaining the size of cell dynamically.

Comment: @Ranjit Yes I worked with, the height of a cell can not maintained dynamically, only using autolayout but you have to find it out at run time and then return it using the method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Just simply find the label size that can contain the given text either using core programming or by method sizeThatFits: and return it in row height method as height>44?height:44

Comment: Hello @iHulk help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087274/autolayout-uilabel-in-uitableviewcell?noredirect=1#comment44551858_28087274