# Autolayout UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

I am working with autoLayout and new to it,

I have a UITableView Cell as below, UITableViewCell height is dynamic, so it has varying height based on the text.

[image]

[image]

I have two labels A and B, which can have variable length text, but the width is fixed, and my **UITableViewCell has dynamic height**, so how can I keep them at center right and maintain equal distance from top and bottom of the cell, as seen in the above two images.

Comment: Have a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Comment: this doesnt help kampai

Answer (score 1):

To put the both labels in centre, you must put them in one view and then set that view in centre. so lets start and create a view say a labelContainer. as shown below
[image]

Set the constrains as shown in picture except the Fixed height, so final constrains will be as fixe trailing space to super view, fixed width and align vertical centre to super view.

Now create two label as you want inside the labelContainer view as shown below picture.
[image]
Now your label will have constrains as labelA- fixed width, fixed top and trailing space to container view and fixed bottom space to label B. and for labelB- fixed width, fixed bottom and trailing space to container view and fixed top space to label A

now your all constrains will look like as.

[image]

Hope this will work. **But do not forget to set the label as sizeToFitContent and number of lines as 0**

Comment: Hello @iHulk, its no working, so I am sending you my demo project, can you please make changes to it and send it back, that would be easy for me to understand. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xg8mli7r9ht1496/Huckleberry.zip?dl=0

Comment: what is happening is that, when the cell size increases containerView height increases, but the containerView height should increase only when the height of label A and B increases to fit them properly.

Comment: Hello @iHulk, you have set constraints first to view and then to labels right?

Comment: Hello @iHulk, its working as expected, but  I have a doubt, I want one more view, which will be the parent of the yellowView and its length will depend on the cell height. As previously we had the yellowView, which used to increase in height as the cell height increases.

Comment: @Ranjit if you want your labels to be in centre, independent of the cell height then you have to calculate the height of cell programatically as in this project https://www.dropbox.com/s/x89i5ck0gs9fy3o/Testing.zip?dl=0

Comment: Or if not so, I mean the cell height depend on labels then do as it in this project https://www.dropbox.com/s/u065udmm0tgj3n5/Huckleberry.zip?dl=0

Comment: thanks for sending two projects, but my issue is not solved, I think I could not explain it properly, what I meant was the two labels should be always at the center of the cell, irrespective of cell height. Cell height will be determined by some other text.

Comment: @Ranjit Try the first project (Testing.zip), it is what you want just ignore the calculateCellHeight method here you can return the hard coded value like 400 or something, the auto layout will work fine, because here your yellow colour view height depends on label text not on cell height.

Answer (score 0):

In your case what is best is to create another view on which the two labels are added as the subviews. The constraints are a bit hard to setup and mistakes are easy to be made so read carefully.

1. Create a view which will hold both of the labels. Let us call it `content`. You set the constraints to superview to be at the right most position and center vertically. Next set the width of the `content` view which seems to be fixed in your case.
2. Create the two labels and put them on the `content` view. Let us call them `top` (the top label) and `bottom` (the bottom label). Set their left and right constraints to their super view (`content`) and set the vertical offset between them to 0 (or whatever you want actually).
3. Now the funny part: Set the `top` top constraint to `content` top and then double-click the constraint and reverse so that the first item is `content` and the second is `top`. Do the same for `bottom` except pin to bottom: Set the bottom constraint of `bottom` to superview and then reverse the objects on the constraint so that the `content` is first and then `bottom`.

This procedure can also be done for horizontal alignment. The key is to tell the superview to be pinned to their subviews rather then the subviews pinned to their superview. So basically what happens here is the superview size will depend on the labels size. After that you may simply pin the superview to the center and it works. Just be careful on the order of objects in constraints.

Comment: how to set,left and right constraint of top and bottom to their superView(content)

Comment: On the navigator (on the left) click and hold your mouse button from each of the labels while holding control key (ctrl) then drag to content and release. A menu for constraints will show. Leading and trailing space are left and right.

Comment: ok, let me try, third point has just bounced, I will get back to you

Comment: I think it would be better, if I would send you my sample project where you can make edits, so it will be easy to understand. What say, shall I send it you

Comment: shall I send you a dropbox link?

Comment: Whatever you prefer. But continue the communication on the mail pleas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69385/discussion-between-ranjit-and-matic-oblak).